# muliple markers

Tags: java, android

i am getting this err:

```
 "Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
 LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
 LocalVariableDeclarationStatement"
```

i am not getting any thig missing

```
TimerTask getMessagesTask=new TimerTask() {
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runable(){


            @Override
            public void run() {

                      newMessages=connectToserverforincomingmsgs( getmsgurl, chatnumber);
                        TextView tv=new TextView(Chat.this);                   
                        tv.setText(chatnumber+":"+newMessages);
                        LayoutParams param=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        tv.setLayoutParams(param);
                        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_chat)).addView(tv);

        }});
```

> ***Blockquote***

Comment: Add one more brace'{' to close TimerTask at the end

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
final Runnable doTaskRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 newMessages=connectToserverforincomingmsgs( getmsgurl, chatnumber);
                 TextView tv=new TextView(Chat.this);                   
                 tv.setText(chatnumber+":"+newMessages);
                 LayoutParams param=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                 tv.setLayoutParams(param);
                 ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_chat)).addView(tv);
            }
        };

        TimerTask getMessagesTask = new TimerTask(){
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(doTaskRunnable);
            }
        };
```

this code will work because Both the TimerTask and the Runnable require you to implement a run method, so you'll need two run methods.